# How to divide up utilities amongst tenants?

Tags: accounting, rent, utilities

Let's say I have two tenants who share my apartment with me. It is agreed that utilities shall be divided equally amongst us. However, one tenant has, as part of his lease, a stipulation that all utilities are provided free with his rent.

My question is this, how do I calculate the utility charge for me and the other tenant? Do I divide by 2, or 3?